# Что это за view элемент на скриншоте?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, material-design, design

Что это за `view` элемент на скриншоте ? который белый и на нем размещены сообщения, или как так можно сделать что на вертикальной ориентации список отражался полностью(Мобильный), а на горизонтальной были отступы по бакам и так сказать заходил на `toolbar`(Планшеты)

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего это просто разные значения отступов слева и справа для разных ориентаций/размеров экрана.

А наползание списка на `AppBarLayout`, [задаётся атрибутом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039075/3212712) `app:behavior_overlapTop`